# Pyomo non-linear constraint to linear

Tags: linear-programming, pyomo

As part of a battery storage revenue maximization model, I am trying to model the following non-linear constraint that calculated the actual energy delivered by the battery to the system based on its current state of charge:
[image: MathJax render]

Here '$E_{act,m}, E_{exp,m} and SOC_{m}$' are intermediate model variables used to calculate battery revenues. The other quantities are model parameters whose values are known.

As I try to linearise the model, I am using the big-M method like so:

```py
def E_act_m(model, m):
    yield model.E_act_m[m] >= model.E_exp_m[m] - M * (1 - model.b1)
    yield model.E_act_m[m] >= 0.01 * (model.SOC_min - model.SOC_m[m]) * model.E_rated - M * (1 - model.b1)
    yield model.E_act_m[m] <= model.E_exp_m[m] + M * (1 - model.b2)
    yield model.E_act_m[m] <= 0.01 * (model.SOC_max - model.SOC_m[m]) * model.E_rated + M * (1 - model.b2)
    yield model.b1 + model.b2 == 1
model.E_act = pyo.Constraint (model.m, rule=E_act_m)
```

where b1 and b2 are binary variables. I am not sure about the implementation. Could someone please advise on the method?